# How to make a container scroll-able?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The current state of my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      decoration: Grad2(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // ...
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Which resulted in this beautiful Login page, but there is a problem (Bottom overflowed by 45 pixels when keyboard is up):

[image: No problem Login page]

[image: Bottom overflowed by 45 pixels when keyboard is up]

So i tried to use the `SingleChildScrollView` but then it resulted in a blank screen:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: BoxConstraints().maxHeight),
    child: Container(
      decoration: Grad2(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // ...
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

But what I've got instead is a white screen. May I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I could make the `Container` the height of the display, which works by setting the height of the `Container` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`. In conclusion, use

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    decoration: Grad2(),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: Grad2(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // ...
            ],
          ),
       ),
    );
}
```

Comment: What I've got is a page that is scrollable, but the gradient wouldn't persist and the `Column` is not centered, refer there https://imgur.com/v8lOVQ6